# lxc 1.1.2 on Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, docker, lxc

I am running lxc 0.8.0 inside Debian Squeeze (Linux kernel 3.4.34). Does anyone run lxc 1.1 or newer inside Linux kernel 3.4? As I know, docker require Linux kernel version at least 3.16. What is the minimum version of Linux kernel to support lxc 1.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you compile it from source? Damn near any version that you can load the required libs for.

Sidenote: I found Proxmox to be more flexible than docker.